# How to change our own application language from device languages list in android?

Tags: android, localization, device

I want to change my application language dynamically not enter any hard coded string language like"us""uk" etc
I want to get device languages list.
Important thing is i want to open languages list on activity like in dialog list not setting.e.g when user press the text-view device all language list opened and when user selected any language that language will be set on same text-view that he/she pressed and also at same time whole app language change. By default one language is selected, e.g English.

Please help me in form of code and also some information either its work on "OnActivityResult" or any other process. i google very much i found every where static code means hard code string.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the selected language of the device with

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```

and you can set language with (for English)

```
Locale.setDefault("en")
```

EDIT:

This is the source code of CustomLocale App from Android Emulators
[image]

```
package com.android.customlocale;


import android.app.ActivityManagerNative;
import android.app.IActivityManager;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Displays the list of system locales as well as maintain a custom list of user
 * locales. The user can select a locale and apply it or it can create or remove
 * a custom locale.
 */
public class CustomLocaleActivity extends ListActivity {

private static final String CUSTOM_LOCALES_SEP = " ";
private static final String CUSTOM_LOCALES = "custom_locales";
private static final String KEY_CUSTOM = "custom";
private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
private static final String KEY_CODE = "code";

private static final String TAG = "LocaleSetup";
private static final boolean DEBUG = true;

/** Request code returned when the NewLocaleDialog activity finishes. */
private static final int UPDATE_LIST = 42;
/** Menu item id for applying a locale */
private static final int MENU_APPLY = 43;
/** Menu item id for removing a custom locale */
private static final int MENU_REMOVE = 44;

/** List view displaying system and custom locales. */
private ListView mListView;
/** Textview used to display current locale */
private TextView mCurrentLocaleTextView;
/** Private shared preferences of this activity. */
private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

    Button newLocaleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_locale);

    newLocaleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(CustomLocaleActivity.this, NewLocaleDialog.class);
            startActivityForResult(i, UPDATE_LIST);
        }
    });

    mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    mListView.setFocusable(true);
    mListView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    mListView.requestFocus();
    registerForContextMenu(mListView);
    setupLocaleList();

    mCurrentLocaleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current_locale);
    displayCurrentLocale();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == UPDATE_LIST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        String locale = data.getExtras().getString(NewLocaleDialog.INTENT_EXTRA_LOCALE);
        if (locale != null && locale.length() > 0) {
            // Get current custom locale list
            String customLocales = mPrefs.getString(CUSTOM_LOCALES, null);

            // Update
            if (customLocales == null) {
                customLocales = locale;
            } else {
                customLocales += CUSTOM_LOCALES_SEP + locale;
            }

            // Save prefs
            if (DEBUG) {
                Log.d(TAG, "add/customLocales: " + customLocales);
            }
            mPrefs.edit().putString(CUSTOM_LOCALES, customLocales).commit();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Added custom locale: " + locale, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            // Update list view
            setupLocaleList();

            // Find the item to select it in the list view
            ListAdapter a = mListView.getAdapter();
            for (int i = 0; i < a.getCount(); i++) {
                Object o = a.getItem(i);
                if (o instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
                    String code = ((Map<String, String>) o).get(KEY_CODE);
                    if (code != null && code.equals(locale)) {
                        mListView.setSelection(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (data.getExtras().getBoolean(NewLocaleDialog.INTENT_EXTRA_SELECT)) {
                selectLocale(locale);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void setupLocaleList() {
    if (DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Update locate list");
    }

    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    // Insert all system locales
    String[] locales = getAssets().getLocales();
    for (String locale : locales) {
        Locale loc = new Locale(locale);

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(1);
        map.put(KEY_CODE, locale);
        map.put(KEY_NAME, loc.getDisplayName());
        data.add(map);
    }
    locales = null;

    // Insert all custom locales
    String customLocales = mPrefs.getString(CUSTOM_LOCALES, "");
    if (DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "customLocales: " + customLocales);
    }
    for (String locale : customLocales.split(CUSTOM_LOCALES_SEP)) {
        if (locale != null && locale.length() > 0) {
            Locale loc = new Locale(locale);

            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(1);
            map.put(KEY_CODE, locale);
            map.put(KEY_NAME, loc.getDisplayName() + " [Custom]");
            // the presence of the "custom" key marks it as custom.
            map.put(KEY_CUSTOM, "");
            data.add(map);
        }
    }

    // Sort all locales by code
    Collections.sort(data, new Comparator<Map<String, String>>() {
        public int compare(Map<String, String> lhs, Map<String, String> rhs) {
            return lhs.get(KEY_CODE).compareTo(rhs.get(KEY_CODE));
        }
    });

    // Update the list view adapter
    mListView.setAdapter(new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
            KEY_CODE, KEY_NAME}, new int[] {R.id.locale_code, R.id.locale_name}));
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    if (menuInfo instanceof AdapterContextMenuInfo) {
        int position = ((AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo).position;
        Object o = mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        if (o instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
            String locale = ((Map<String, String>) o).get(KEY_CODE);
            String custom = ((Map<String, String>) o).get(KEY_CUSTOM);

            if (custom == null) {
                menu.setHeaderTitle("System Locale");
                menu.add(0, MENU_APPLY, 0, "Apply");
            } else {
                menu.setHeaderTitle("Custom Locale");
                menu.add(0, MENU_APPLY, 0, "Apply");
                menu.add(0, MENU_REMOVE, 0, "Remove");
            }
        }
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    String pendingLocale = null;
    boolean is_custom = false;

    ContextMenuInfo menuInfo = item.getMenuInfo();
    if (menuInfo instanceof AdapterContextMenuInfo) {
        int position = ((AdapterContextMenuInfo) menuInfo).position;
        Object o = mListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        if (o instanceof Map<?, ?>) {
            pendingLocale = ((Map<String, String>) o).get(KEY_CODE);
            is_custom = ((Map<String, String>) o).get(KEY_CUSTOM) != null;
        }
    }

    if (pendingLocale == null) {
        // should never happen
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    if (item.getItemId() == MENU_REMOVE) {
        // Get current custom locale list
        String customLocales = mPrefs.getString(CUSTOM_LOCALES, "");

        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Remove " + pendingLocale + " from custom locales: " + customLocales);
        }

        // Update
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String locale : customLocales.split(CUSTOM_LOCALES_SEP)) {
            if (locale != null && locale.length() > 0 && !locale.equals(pendingLocale)) {
                if (sb.length() > 0) {
                    sb.append(CUSTOM_LOCALES_SEP);
                }
                sb.append(locale);
            }
        }
        String newLocales = sb.toString();
        if (!newLocales.equals(customLocales)) {
            // Save prefs
            mPrefs.edit().putString(CUSTOM_LOCALES, customLocales).commit();

            Toast.makeText(this, "Removed custom locale: " + pendingLocale, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    } else if (item.getItemId() == MENU_APPLY) {
        selectLocale(pendingLocale);
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}

private void selectLocale(String locale) {
    if (DEBUG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Select locale " + locale);
    }

    try {
        IActivityManager am = ActivityManagerNative.getDefault();
        Configuration config = am.getConfiguration();

        Locale loc = null;

        String[] langCountry = locale.split("_");
        if (langCountry.length == 2) {
            loc = new Locale(langCountry[0], langCountry[1]);
        } else {
            loc = new Locale(locale);
        }

        config.locale = loc;

        // indicate this isn't some passing default - the user wants this
        // remembered
        config.userSetLocale = true;

        am.updateConfiguration(config);

        Toast.makeText(this, "Select locale: " + locale, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Select locale failed", e);
        }
    }
}

private void displayCurrentLocale() {
    try {
        IActivityManager am = ActivityManagerNative.getDefault();
        Configuration config = am.getConfiguration();

        if (config.locale != null) {
            String text = String.format("%s - %s",
                    config.locale.toString(),
                    config.locale.getDisplayName());
            mCurrentLocaleTextView.setText(text);
        }
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            Log.e(TAG, "get current locale failed", e);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: But this will give me only single selected language. i want to get whole language list first not from Resources list only from device list and than on my choice which language i wanted to select and change application language.

Comment: Edited the answer... I think this is what you want